# How to convert "2019-11-02T20:18:00Z" to timestamp in HQL?

Tags: sql, hive, timestamp, hiveql, unix-timestamp

I have datetime string `"2019-11-02T20:18:00Z"`. How can I convert it into timestamp in Hive HQL?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want preserve milliseconds then remove `Z`, replace `T` with space and convert to timestamp:

```
select timestamp(regexp_replace("2019-11-02T20:18:00Z", '^(.+?)T(.+?)Z$','$1 $2'));
```

Result:

```
2019-11-02 20:18:00
```

Also it works with milliseconds:

```
 select timestamp(regexp_replace("2019-11-02T20:18:00.123Z", '^(.+?)T(.+?)Z$','$1 $2'));
```

Result:

```
2019-11-02 20:18:00.123
```

Using `from_unixtime(unix_timestamp())` solution does not work with milliseconds.
Demo:

```
  select from_unixtime(unix_timestamp("2019-11-02T20:18:00.123Z", "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSS'Z'"));
```

Result:

```
2019-11-02 20:18:00
```

Milliseconds are lost. And the reason is that [**function unix_timestamp returns seconds** passed from the UNIX epoch (1970-01-01 00:00:00 UTC)](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/Hive/LanguageManual+UDF#LanguageManualUDF-DateFunctions).

Answer (score 2):

**try this:**

```
select from_unixtime(unix_timestamp("2019-11-02T20:18:00Z", "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss"))
```