# Hive - calculating string type timestamp differences in minutes

Tags: sql, hive, casting, timestamp, hiveql

I'm novice to SQL (in hive) and trying to calculate every anonymousid's time spent between first event and last event in minutes. The resource table's timestamp is formatted as string,
like: "2020-12-24T09:47:17.775Z". I've tried in two ways:

1- Cast column timestamp to bigint and calculated the difference from main table.

`select anonymousid, max(from_unixtime(cast('timestamp' as bigint)) - min(from_unixtime(cast('timestamp' as bigint)) from db1.formevent group by anonymousid`

I got NULLs after implementing this as a solution.

2- Create a new table from main resource, put conditions to call with 'where' and tried to convert 'timestamp' to date format without any min-max calculation.

`create table db1.successtime as select anonymousid, pagepath,buttontype, itemname, 'location', cast(to_date(from_unixtime(unix_timestamp('timestamp', "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSS"),'HH:mm:ss') as date)  from db1.formevent where pagepath = "/account/sign-up/" and itemname = "Success" and 'location' = "Standard"`

Then I got NULLs again and I left. [It looks like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xQAjN.png)

Is there any way I can reformat and calculate time difference **in minutes** between first and last event ('timestamp') and take the average grouped by 'location'?

Comment: See this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/57497316/2700344 Divide by 60 to get minutes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
select anonymousid,
       (max(unix_timestamp(timestamp, "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSS'Z'")) - 
        min(unix_timestamp(timestamp, "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSS'Z'")) 
       ) / 60
from db1.formevent
group by anonymousid;
```

Comment: Thank you. I got zero's as an output. I think It's calculating the hourly difference, should I change the divisor? @leftjoin

Comment: @Ipek Check this example: `select unix_timestamp('2020-12-24T09:47:17.775Z', "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSS'Z'")-
       unix_timestamp('2020-12-24T09:47:00.775Z', "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSS'Z'")`  Result=17 unix_timestamp gives seconds (bigint). milliseconds are lost if you are converting like this

Comment: @Ipek Read also this post about milliseconds: https://stackoverflow.com/a/58713989/2700344

Comment: @Ipek @Ipek Milliseconds precision (seconds.milliseconds): `select cast(timestamp(regexp_replace("2019-11-02T20:18:12.123Z", '^(.+?)T(.+?)Z$','$1 $2')) as double)-
cast(timestamp(regexp_replace("2019-11-02T20:18:11.000Z", '^(.+?)T(.+?)Z$','$1 $2')) as double) `

Comment: @Ipek But better to extract and process milliseconds part separately as int to eliminate issues with double precision

Answer (score 0):

From your description, this should work:

```
select anonymousid,
       (max(unix_timestamp(timestamp, 'yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSS'),'HH:mm:ss') - 
        min(unix_timestamp(timestamp, 'yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSS'),'HH:mm:ss') 
       ) / 60
from db1.formevent
group by anonymousid;
```

Note that the column name is not in single quotes.